# View losing ability to accept key events

Tags: android, focus, keyevent, glsurfaceview, key-events

I'm a little confused over how key events (back key, volume keys) relate to Views in android.

Take for example the problem I currently have:

**Working OK**

- Create Layout (for example, Relative layout)
- Add View to Layout (A GL SurfaceView)
- Run app and wait for everything to load (and for GLSurfaceView to be created)
- Press home key
- Re-launch app
- Press back to exit

**Not Working OK**

- Create Layout (for example, Relative layout)
- Add View to Layout
- Run app and **press home key before GLSurfaceView is fully create/displayed**
- Re-launch app quickly again **before GLSurfaceView is fully create/displayed**
- Wait for SurfaceView to be displayed
- Although touch events work **Keys no longer work and app can't be exited**

why is this? Is there anyway to get focus back to this view?  (if 'focus' is the correct terminology in  this example).

I've tried

```
myGLView.requestFocus();
```

I've also tried various other methods but nothing seems to work - surely there must be a quick and easy way to make sure key events work with the currently visible GLSurfaceView?

Comment: "app can't be exited" -- are you saying that the "home" key stops working after you quickly exit and return to an app?  What device and version of Android are you using?

Comment: No @fadden, the home key still works, but the back key (and volume keys) stop working - it's KitKat 4.4.4. on a Google Nexus 10 tablet :-)